# loading indicator code doesn't work on jquery 1.10

Tags: jquery

This works on jquery 1.8

```
$(function() {
    var $loader = $("#loading-indicator"),
        timer;

    $("#loading-indicator").css('visibility','hidden').ajaxSend(function() {
        timer && clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $loader.css('visibility','visible');
        }, 50);
    }).ajaxComplete(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $loader.css('visibility','hidden');
    });
});
```

`#loading-indicator` just doesn't show up..

Which methods changed on 1.10?

Answer (score 1):

solved with

```
$(function() {
    var $loader = $("#loading-indicator"),
        timer;
$loader.css('visibility','hidden');
    $(document).ajaxSend(function() {
        timer && clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $loader.css('visibility','visible');
        }, 50);
    }).ajaxComplete(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $loader.css('visibility','hidden');
    });
});
```

as of 1.8, ajaxStart should be attached to document.. 
on 1.8.3 it did work.. hmmm